# What is the path for a font symfony

Tags: php, symfony, fonts

I am trying to do some text and convert it into an image.

I got some code from the php manual.

Im working on it in symfony 3.1

The only problem that I have is how do you set the path for the font.

The roboto-regular.ttf is in my **/web** directory.

My code:

```
    //setting the content type
    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    // Create the image
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(400,30);

    // Create Some colors
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

    // The text to draw
    $text = 'Testing';
    // Replace path by your font path
    $font = 'Roboto-Regular.ttf';

    // Add some shadow to the text
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

    // Add the text
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

    // Using imagepng() resulst in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually no direct way to get path to webdir in Symfony2 as the framework is completely independent of the webdir.
But you can use `getRootDir()`:

```
$path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->get('request')->getBasePath();
```

`$this->get('request')->getBasePath();` will directly put you in web directory